# Failed to install Qt on Win10 WSL2 (ubuntu 16.04) with error: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt

When i tried to install Qt on WSL2 ubuntu, i got below errors:

```
root@sun-pc:/mnt/e# ls -l qt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sun sun  157714525 May 30 09:51 qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.9.1.run
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sun sun  176152456 May 30 09:52 qt-creator-opensource-windows-x86_64-4.9.1.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sun sun 1458369997 Jun  5 11:24 qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.3.run
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sun sun 3933849864 Jun  5 11:33 qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.12.3.exe
root@sun-pc:/mnt/e# ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.3.run
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981317/why-do-i-get-warning-qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-every-time-for-a) but it did not help.
How can i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir) post does not help, either.

Comment: See the last error. You maynot have proper X server. Follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/